# ASP.NET Repeater bind List<string>

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I am binding a `List<string>` to a Repeater control. Now I want to use the `Eval` function 
to display the contents in `ItemTemplate` like

```
<%# Eval("NAME") %>.
```

But I am not sure what I should use instead of NAME.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Just use `<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>`

If you are worried about null values you may want to refactor to this (.NET 6+)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem?.ToString() ?? string.Empty%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Note if you are using less than .NET 6 you cannot use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) Container.DataItem?.ToString()

Answer (score 28):

Set the ItemType to System.String

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="System.String" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Item %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Note that the ItemType property is introduced in .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 10):

```
rptSample.DataSource = from c in lstSample select new { NAME = c };
```

in the repeater you put

```
<%# Eval("NAME") %>
```

Comment: Some examples use <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NAME") %> instead of simply using Eval. What's the difference?

Answer (score 9):

This should work just fine:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <%=this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4):

A more complete example based on the LINQ provided by @RobertoBr:

**In code behind:**

```
List<string> notes = new List<string>();
notes.Add("Value1")
notes.Add("Value2")

repeaterControl1.DataSource = from c in notes select new {NAME = c};
repeaterControl1.DataBind();
```

**On page:**

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterControl1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("NAME")  %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the databind syntax here or it will not work.

```
<%# this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Item Template

```
     <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblName"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YourEntityName").ToString() ==""? "NA" : Eval("YourEntityName").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
    <ItemTemplate>
```

or Simply Add inside Item Template

```
<%# Eval("YourEntityName").ToString() ==""? "NA" : Eval("YourEntityName").ToString()%>
```