# Bind distinct data to repeater using linq to object distinct

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I am trying to filter records basis on distinct . I used the following code

```
List<BALHotelList> searchresult = (from a in bh
                                           join b in hr on a.HotelCode equals b.hotelCode
                                           orderby a.HotelName
                                           select new BALHotelList
                                               {
                                                   HotelCode = a.HotelCode,
                                                   ImageURL_Text = a.ImageURL_Text,
                                                   HotelName = a.HotelName,
                                                   StarRating = a.StarRating,
                                                   HotelAddress = a.HotelAddress,
                                                   Destination = a.Destination,
                                                   Country = a.Country,
                                                   HotelInfo = a.HotelInfo,
                                                   Latitude = a.Latitude,
                                                   Longitude = a.Longitude,
                                                   HotelArea=a.HotelArea,
                                                   totalPrice = b.totalPrice,
                                                   totalPriceSpecified = b.totalPriceSpecified,
                                                   totalSalePrice = b.totalSalePrice,
                                                   totalSalePriceSpecified = b.totalSalePriceSpecified,
                                                   rooms = b.rooms,
                                                   boardType = b.boardType

                                               }).ToList();

        var uniqueArea =searchresult.Select(m => m.HotelArea).Distinct();


  rptHotelArea.DataSource = uniqueArea;
        rptHotelArea.DataBind();
```

but it's not finding HotelArea in data source .

but when i debug its shows me all distinct values in `uniqueArea`

the error is as following:

**`DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'HotelArea'.`**

**EDITED**

Here is repeater HTML

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptHotelArea" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="sub-part1">
                <a href="#"><%#Eval("HotelArea")%></a></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011617/asp-net-repeater-bind-liststring.

Comment: @Serge +1 its works . one more thing whether null be treated as unique in distinct case

Comment: yes i want to skip null values

Comment: var uniqueArea =searchresult.Select(m => m.HotelArea).Where(m => m != null).Distinct();

Comment: and what about empety string ? please post your comments as answer so i can accept it . Its more near then jon answer

Comment: okay, I've moved my comments to the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've moved my answers here.

Part 1:
[ASP.NET Repeater bind List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011617/asp-net-repeater-bind-liststring)

Part 2:
Skip null and empty strings:

```
var uniqueArea =searchresult.Select(m => m.HotelArea).Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already selected `HotelArea` here:

```
var uniqueArea = searchresult.Select(m => m.HotelArea).Distinct();
```

... so in your databinding you should just select the value itself.

If you need the whole information within the data source, rather than *just* the hotel area, you'd need something like `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com).

Comment: yes, and var uniqueArea show me the list of string when i debug of distinct HotelArea , but it fails when i bind this to repeater data source

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Yes, because I'm sure in the code you haven't shown use, you're specifying a binding which tries to find a property called HotelArea *within* each value.

Comment: i edited my code to show  use of uniqueArea, Please check edited part

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Right - see that `Eval("HotelArea")` bit - that's what's trying to find the `HotelArea` part. By that point you've already got the string; you just need the value itself...

Comment: how can i modify my this clause var uniqueArea =searchresult.Select(m => m.HotelArea).Distinct(); to get HotelArea in datasource so repeater works

Comment: thanks , i got answer from @Serge comment i changed the repeater HTML like this    <a href="#"><%#Container.DataItem%></a> and its works now. I want to know one more thing will distinct treat null as unique element

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Yes, that's a separate value.