# Trying to get data to display in textareas using c# Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the following code to try to display a series of textareas using  but no data is being displayed.

I have written the following:

```
string rolesString = dr["TheRole"].ToString().TrimEnd(';');
            List<string> rolesList = new List<string>(rolesString.Split(';'));
            uxRolesList.DataSource = rolesList;
            uxRolesList.DataBind();
```

Where rolesString should look something like this:

```
rolesString = "Test 1; Test 2; Test 3";
```

And also:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxRolesList" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="uxTxtBoxRole" runat="server" rows="5" columns="100" 
                TextMode="multiline"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br /><br />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But all I get is a series of textareas with no data in them. I'm very new to asp.net and c# so please be gentle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in the text `<%# Container.DataItem %>` like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="uxTxtBoxRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
     columns="100"  rows="5" TextMode="multiline"></asp:TextBox>
```

More Details
[ASP.NET Repeater bind List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011617/asp-net-repeater-bind-liststring)

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew I was missing something :)