# How to include block of HTML code when looping through multiple lists on CodeBehind

Tags: c#, jquery, html, list, code-behind

So I have **2 lists** on CodeBehind, `List<List<string>>` and `List<string>`. Below is the code for the 2 lists.

```
            loadTest1 = new List<string>();
            loadTest2 = new List<string>();
            loadTest3 = new List<string>();
            loadTest4 = new List<string>();

            loadTestList.Add(loadTest1);
            loadTestList.Add(loadTest2);
            loadTestList.Add(loadTest3);
            loadTestList.Add(loadTest4);
```

I am planning to display **EVERY string** inside the **4 loadtest Lists** content on a `hidden div`. Below is the **logic structure** of what I am planning to implement. I want to generate an **HTML CHIP** for **each string** on **all loadTests.**

```
        foreach (List<string> test in loadTestList)
        {
            foreach (string value in test)
            {
               <div class="chip">
                 value
               </div>
            }
        }
```

How can I also **append** it in the `hidden div`? Are there any **plugins** that I could use to make this easier?

Comment: Is `hidden div` a container that contains all of these `chip` divs? Not sure if I understand how that comes into play.

Comment: Yes, `hidden div` would contain all the `chip` divs. Then it would show when I hover on another div which I have an idea on how to implement. @dana

Answer (score 1):

You could inline the code/values.  Below is some skeleton code. If you provide more of your HTML structure, then I could probably improve this.

**SamplePage.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SamplePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace.SamplePage" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hidden">
    <%
    foreach (var list in LoadTestList)
    {
        foreach (string value in list)
        {
    %>
           <div class="chip">
             <%:value%>
           </div>
    <%
        }
    }
    %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is should also be noted that `loadTestList` should be declared at the class level.

**SamplePage.cs.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class SamplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected List<List<string>> LoadTestList;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> loadTest1 = new List<string> { "a1", "b1", "c1" };
            List<string> loadTest2 = new List<string> { "a2", "b2", "c2" };
            List<string> loadTest3 = new List<string> { "a3", "b3", "c3" };
            List<string> loadTest4 = new List<string> { "a4", "b4", "c4" };

            LoadTestList = new List<List<string>>();
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest1);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest2);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest3);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest4);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <div class="hidden">

           <div class="chip">
             a1
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             b1
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             c1
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             a2
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             b2
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             c2
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             a3
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             b3
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             c3
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             a4
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             b4
           </div>

           <div class="chip">
             c4
           </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some more info from the OP would be good here. IIf they are using web forms (as hinted by the term CodeBegind) this would also open up the use of a repeater control.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Dana's great answer I'm going to move a little more of the work to the code behind. I'm generally a fan of leaving html manipulation in aspx pages but in this case, I think it's worthwhile moving it to the code behind.

**SamplePage.cs.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class SamplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected List<List<string>> LoadTestList;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> loadTest1 = new List<string> { "a1", "b1", "c1" };
            List<string> loadTest2 = new List<string> { "a2", "b2", "c2" };
            List<string> loadTest3 = new List<string> { "a3", "b3", "c3" };
            List<string> loadTest4 = new List<string> { "a4", "b4", "c4" };

            LoadTestList = new List<List<string>>();
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest1);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest2);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest3);
            LoadTestList.Add(loadTest4);
        }
    }

    public string GetChips()
    {
        //First let's flatten the list with linq
        List<string> flatList = LoadTestList.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

        //Now lets use Join to create the basis of out output;
        string output = String.Join("</div>"  + Environment.NewLine + "<div class=\"chip\">", flatList

        //We need to manually add the first and last div tags
        output =  string.Format("<div class=\"chip\">{0}</div>", output);

        //You could reduce all this to one line but I've broken up the steps for clarity.
        return output;
    }
}
```

**SamplePage.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SamplePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace.SamplePage" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hidden">
    <%= GetChips() %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note** If you're using asp.net WebForms you could use a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) control with the flattened [list as the data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011617/asp-net-repeater-bind-liststring).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create multiple div with chips class & want to display string in each div. Please try this  below code

```
foreach (List<string> test in loadTestList)
        {
            foreach (string value in test)
            {
            var html='   <div class="chip">'+value+'</div>'
                 //Append it in hidden div with ID=divHidden
             $('#divHidden').append(html);
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Above code is for Javascript

In CodeBehind you can do like this

```
foreach (List<string> test in loadTestList)
            {
                foreach (string value in test)
                {
               var r  = document.createElement('Div');
      r.CssClass ="chip";
r.InnerHtml = value;
document.getElementById('divHidden').appendChild(r);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Both options still look a lot like javascript, one using jquery. Do you know what the OP means by codebehind when it comes to C#?

Comment: What did you mean by OP? @JonP

Comment: OP = Original Poster

Comment: @JonP Not sure, what exactly you want to say. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Basically it looks like you are mixing javascript (`document.createElement`) with C# (`List<string>`) and have no idea of what the concept of **CodeBehind** is in the context of C#

Comment: @JonP I afraid , you are not familiar with **C# CodeBehind**  . I have used following code in my project & it's running fine.   void image1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            document = HtmlPage.Document;
            HtmlElement select = document.GetElementByID("Select1");
            HtmlElement option = document.CreateElement("option");
            option.SetAttribute("innerText", i.ToString());//IE
            option.SetAttribute("textContent", i.ToString());//FireFox
            select.AppendChild(option);
        }  .

Comment: I didn't downvote, but agree with @JonP that this looks like a mixture of C# and JavaScript.

Comment: C# Code behind in this context refers to the C# code running behind a web page, be it an MVC view or WebForms page on a web server. As such there is no direct interface with the client side DOM. It looks like your code is for a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control in a windows form project. Again this is not relevant to the original problem.