# Databinding a List of string to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Coming from this question [ASP.NET Repeater bind List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011617/asp-net-repeater-bind-liststring) I tried following:

ASP:

```
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div><img src='<%# Eval("Container.DataItem") %>' /></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

C#:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = new List<string>(){ "http://foo.jpg" };
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

should work but i get this error:

> System.String does not contain a property with the name Container

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eval method tring reflect to Container.DataItem property on string item. you need directli use Container.DataItem

change

```
<img src='<%# Eval("Container.DataItem") %>' />
```

to

```
<img src='<%#Container.DataItem%>' />
```